# Send a HTTP-POST Request Through Android Button

Tags: java, android, xmlhttprequest

*I have to send an HTTP-Request (through an Android button) to a Java Servlet.*

I am stuck where I have to put the information (code) and what it must contain in order to send it.

**Context:** User Logs in --> Clicks on "Grant Access" --> Sends an HTTP-Request to Java Servlet(for example 192.168.1.1)

**Note:** I'm just a beginner in Android.

I know that it has to do with the ID of the button "Grant Access".

**AndroidManifest:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mertino11.ourapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".FireApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".AccountActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

**Activity_main_xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="163dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/snetech"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/emailField"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/passwordField"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity_account (If user logs successful):**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_account"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mertino11.ourapplication.AccountActivity">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="logout"
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Grant Access"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/grantAccess"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/logout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Main Menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**The Java Classes I use:**
**AccountActivity**

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    public class AccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

        Button logout=(Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(AccountActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });


    }


}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mEmailField;
    private EditText mPasswordField;

    private Button mLoginBtn;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mEmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
        mPasswordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);

        mLoginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AccountActivity.class));

                }
            }
        };

        mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                startSignIn();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    private void startSignIn() {

        String email = mEmailField.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordField.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fields are empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign In Problem!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }



    }
}
```

**FireApp:**

```
    import android.app.Application;

    import com.firebase.client.Firebase;


    public class FireApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void  onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();

     Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    }
    }
```

[image: Login Screen]
[image: User enters his Main Menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to make an HTTP POST while clicking on button `@+id/grantAccess`.
First you have to add an OnClickListener in your `AccountActivity` class. Like you did it for the `logout` button. In the onClick method you can now make your HTTP request. Therefore you have to create an `AyncTask` because you are not allowed to make HTTP calls over the applications main thread.

```
public class PostTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private static final String ENDPOINT = "http://yourendpoint/";

    PostTask() {
            //add here your variables that you need
    }

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       this.doPost();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute() {
        //do what you want when you are finished
    }

    private void doPost(){
        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        final RequestObject request = new RequestObject();

        //parse the request to a format what is used by your endpoint (json, xml,..)
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(objectToString(request), createHeaders(authResp));
        final HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(ENDPOINT, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
     }
}
```

In your `onClick` method you create an instance of the `PostTask` with:

```
new PostTask().execute((Void) null);
```

Like tudor07 said you can use various http client frameworks. In this case I did it with Spring for Android (http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/). In the link shown there is also a description how to add this library to your project. Visit https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html for a more detail description on the async handling.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to communicate trough HTTP you need an HTTP client framework that can make HTTP request at an URL you specify and with a HTTP method and parameters/body you specify.

One very popular framework for Android is Retrofit.
Retrofit will allow you to make a POST call with whatever parameters you want.

Take a look at how to set up Retrofit and how to create a POST call on their page: https://square.github.io/retrofit/